# ListView not updating after web service Sync

Tags: android, android-listview, android-listfragment, android-syncadapter, android-webservice

I have impelmented `SyncAdapter` that calls webservice and insert/update database. I would like to show some of this data in `ListView` so i implemented `ListFragment` in witch the data is displayed via `CursorAdapter`. And everything works ok, except when I get new data from web and insert it into database, the `CursorAdapter` is not updated and new data is not shown in `ListView`

In my `ContentProvider`, after every insert I call `context.getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);`

This is `ListFragment` part for implementing adapter

```
mAdapter = new ObavijestiAdapter(getActivity(), null, 0);
setListAdapter(mAdapter);
```

and this is my custom adapter

```
public class ObavijestiAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
private Cursor mCursor;
private Context mContext;
private final LayoutInflater mInflater;

static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView hTextNaslov;
    public TextView hTextOpis;
    public ImageView hImage;
}
public ObavijestiAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
    super(context, c, flags);
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();

    //TODO: REMOVE AFTER IMPLEMENTING REAL IMAGE
    int w = 24, h = 24;
    Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888; // see other conf types
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, conf); // this creates a MUTABLE bitmap
    //END REMOVE

    holder.hImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    holder.hTextNaslov.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataContract.Obavijesti.OBAVIJESTI_NASLOV)));
    holder.hTextOpis.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataContract.Obavijesti.OBAVIJESTI_OPIS)));

}


@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_obavijesti_row,parent,false);

    final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.hTextOpis = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.obOpis);
    holder.hTextNaslov = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.obNaslov);
    holder.hImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.oblist_image);
    view.setTag(holder);
    return view;
}
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got this to work. So for anybody trying to do similar thing, you must include `cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);` after your `.query` in the `ContentProvider`. And that is it...

But if you are like me and are receiving data from a web service, remember NOT to put `.notifyDataSetChanged()` on ContentProvider `.update/.insert/.delete` but on a adapter that is calling this methods in `SyncAdapter`. In my example

```
mContentResolver.applyBatch(ScheduleContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY, batch);
mContentResolver.notifyChange(DataContract.Obavijesti.CONTENT_URI, null);
```

I hope, for somebody, this will be helpful

Answer (score -1):

Try invalidating the view you're using after updating the information.

```
listview.invalidate();
```

Comment: Ok... But, my SyncAdapter is doing sync in background, and I don't know where I need to put this `listview.invalidate();`. Because, SyncAdapter doesn't know on what activity I am now (does it have a listview or not, and if my ListFragment is opened, I don't know that the data is changed in SyncAdapter... This is confusing me...